# Piping large data in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I would like to download a file that is about 900MB. The code for achieving this looks like this:

```
function download(url){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
    try{

        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error){
                reject(error)
            } else{
               console.log('sucess')
            }
        }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./test.zip'))
            .on('finish',() =>{
                resolve(promObj);
            })
    } catch (error){
        reject(error);
    }
})
}
```

At the end, I get the following error:

```
buffer.js:556
if (encoding === undefined) return buf.utf8Slice(start, end);
                                     ^

Error: "toString()" failed
```

After some research I found out that the size limit of the node buffer is 256MB.

Is there a possibility to solve this?

Comment: I don't think you can use try/catch with asynchronous code unless you are using async/await pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffer size limit is 2GB:

```
 require("buffer").kMaxLength

 2147483647
```

256MB is the limit of the string

Try just :

```
request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./test.zip'))
```

---- Edit ----

```
request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./test.zip')).on('finish',() =>{
    // your callback here
 })
```

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the limit?

Comment: I don't think so, i think the problem comes from the callback you've inserted in the request before the pipe, with this, the full string is returned in body and you reach the string limit. I don't think you reach the buffer limit,

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I need the callback because I am processing multiple urls one after the other. Could I prevent node from printing the whole body?

Comment: You don't need it, see edit, just put your callback in the on finish event